# Configuring firewall rules

Tags: windows, firewall, proxy, rules

I am trying to configure firewall rules for my windows PC

i would like to achieve this scenario

All packets from PC A will use this proxy server x.x.x.x at port AA

However, these are my rules

```
Allow Local Address x.x.x.x Remote Address Any Local Port AA Remote Port Any
Block Local Address Any Remote Address Any Local Port Any Remote Port Any
```

PC A has ip of `y.y.y.y`

Shouldnt it match the first rule if i am using a proxy server which i configured in the LAN settings.

This works though.

```
Allow Local Address x.x.x.x Remote Address Any Local Port AA Remote Port Any
```

Traffic is routed to my proxy server if i only use one single rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  Windows firewall does not behave like other familiar firewalls.  A BLOCK will always be evaluated before an ALLOW.  The block rule you have above is unnecessary though - blocking is the default approach.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421709%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

My last sentence is incorrect since I misunderstood the original question.  Under the 'advanced settings' window, right click -> properties on 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' in the top left pane.  Set 'Outbound connections' from 'Allow (default)' to 'Block' on whichever profile you're using.  Delete the block rule you made.  Then it will block outbound by default.

Comment: I am talking about outbound rules though

Comment: @aceminer my mistake.  Added the appropriate solution.

Comment: So the rules would be considered an exception I suppose?

Comment: I have just tried and it does not work. It literally blocks all communication even if i had allowed it to go through my proxy

Comment: Yep.  The one rule towards the proxy would be an exception.

Could you please enable logging for blocked (in the same window where you set it to default-block), make a few web requests, and then check the log?  Comment back with a few lines when you get the chance.